# C# - Dependency injection - Repository Layer - Calling select

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I realized a need for dependency injection as I need a new class but couldn't create one as an entity because the class doesn't exist in the database. I successfully did the unity part right.  I am just stuck with calling it. Following code is what I tried, but it doesn't let me use the `select` option. The error I get is

> The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments explicitly

I googled that error but most of the people who posted that error have a long code history behind it which made it difficult for me to understand.

Can anyone see where am I going wrong??

```
   public virtual List<IMcrVolumeAdjustmentMainGrid> GetVolumeAdjustmentByLoadId(Guid? LoadId)
    {
        var AdjustmentGroups = UnitOfWork.Context.Set<McrVolumeAdjustment>()
                .Include(y => y.McrVolumeAdjustmentReason)
                .Where(x => x.McrPickup.McrLoadId == LoadId && x.McrVolumeAdjustmentReason.McrVolumeAdjReasonCode != McrVolumeAdjReasonCodeEnum.LoadRejected)
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.McrVolumeAdjustmentReason, x.EffectiveYear, x.EffectiveMonth, x.LastModifierIdentityName })
                .ToList();
        return AdjustmentGroups.Select(
               x =>
               {
                   var entry = DefaultContainer.Current.Resolve<IMcrVolumeAdjustmentMainGrid>();
                   entry.EffectiveDate = new DateTime(x.Key.EffectiveYear, x.Key.EffectiveMonth, 01);
                   entry.McrReason = x.Key.McrVolumeAdjustmentReason.Description;
                   entry.LastModifierIdentityName = x.Key.LastModifierIdentityName;
                   entry.TotalAdjustment = x.Sum(y => y.AdjustedMilkVolume);
               }
            ).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I cannot do that, the reason is `yourType` means an entity. I need a custom class which isn't representing any table. The main reason I am doing DI :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your SELECT statement is invalid because you return nothing.
You should add "return entry;" code to the end of the select lambda.

Comment: are you sure? because i am returning something

Comment: Yes, your lambda is of void type. You must return "entry" explicitly.